# Trouble with glmer in R Markdown

Tags: markdown, lme4

everyone. I run a code, which definetly works, but in Markdown (knitting) I see this message:

```
 error in glmer(accuracy ~ aspect * time + (1 + aspect * time || item.id) + : could not find function "glmer" 
 Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
```

However, it works if I run only this chunk by clicking on 'Run current chunk' button. I've checked if the last version of the package is installed.

Comment: Try including `library(lme4)` at the top of the chunk.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works :)

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including `library(lme4)` at the top of the chunk.